# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update mariadb can not auto create Database indexes or Foreign key or column

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, spring-boot, create-table

**1.spring boot**

```
spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE
```

**2.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '1.1.8'
}
```

**3.application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**4.Entity**

```
    @Entity public class Users { @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false,unique = true)
    private int userId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Hibernate can not auto create Database indexes or Foreign key or constraint or add column

but,when

```
spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE
```

everything is normal

How to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, mariadb version is too low

```
compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '1.1.8'
```

change to

```
compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '1.5.6'
```

everything is OK !